# Setup async hasMany relationship with default scoped url.

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I trying to optimize my application. I have a model `Job` that hasMany `Todo`s.  Fetching all the jobs from the backend is not efficient because currently I am serializing all the todo_ids for the has many relationship. It seems to me ember-data should be able to setup the hasMany relationship in such a way as to use job_id as the foreign_key.

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  todos: DS.hasMany('todo', {async: true})
})
```

How can I set up the `todos` relationship so the url defaults to something like.

```
job = this.store.find('job',1) //api/jobs/1
job.get('todos') //api/todo?job=1
```

Comment: When you make it async true. Ember automatically makes a query after job is fetched. The URL for the query might look like this `/todos?ids=[1,2,7,8]` where 1,2,7 and 8 todo_ids for the fetched job

Comment: yes that is the inefficient part. IMO it isn't necessary to serialize all the todo_ids when you can filter by the job_id. Like described http://jsonapi.org/format/#urls-relationships

Comment: Good point. I hope this gets implemented in the future ember data releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed by the core team.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2162

I have created a pull request implementing it as well. https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2435.

The current solution is to override the serializers normalizePayload hook and build the links.